# Rails Polymorphic association child different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have 4 models

```
Class Post 
 has_many: videos 
 has_many: documents
 has_many: checklists
end
```

and these models `belongs_to` Post

```
Class Video
end 

Class Document
end 

Class Checklist
end
```

and sample record looks

```
id: 1, name 'sample post', media_type: 'video'
```

It is very hard when I render a single post, I need to check condition what media type every time and use the respective model attributes

eg:

```
@posts.each do |post|
   if @post.media_type =='video'
      render :video_html
   elsif @post.media_type =='document'
     render :document_html
   .....
   ....  
 end
```

I cannot use `polymorphic association` since video, doucments, checklists has different fields.

Please advice to design the model better way

What I need is :

```
@post.media
```

should return the medias like how `polymorphic` works.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: is there any best way to design this model?

Comment: It's impossible to comment meaningfully on your model layer based on your current layer, and with no explanation of how it's not currently working for you, or what your existing schema looks like, or what any of your usecases are.

Comment: Just spitballing here, but you could possibly make a joins between Post and Video/Document, maybe called PostMedia. Where PostMedia `belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true; belongs_to :post` And then Post could `has_many :post_medias`. There you could maybe do `@post.post_medias. each { |post_media| post_media.media_type.eql?('Video') ? render :video_html .... }` Just a quick idea maybe :D

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is simply the large `if` that must account for each video type, there are several ways of cleaning this up.

The *best* way is to just render the collection:

**Don't do this:**

```
@posts.each do |post|
  # ... render the post ...
end
```

**Instead, use collection rendering:**

```
render @posts
```

This will render a partial for each item in the collection. The partial rendered is based on the `partial_path` of each item in the collection, which by default will be something like `app/views/videos/_video.html` for `Video` records,  `app/views/documents/_document.html` for `Document` records, etc. Move your HTML into the places Rails expects to find it, and you're done.

A second way of removing the `if` is to use simple string interpolation:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  render "#{post.media_type}_html"
end
```

But simply using `render @posts` is preferable. It's simpler, and performs faster.

Comment: Thanks @meagar. My intention is to design the model better

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi...how to model something is very subjective and requires too much information for anyone on here to provide you with a concrete answer. This answer, however, provides you with a solid way to refactor your view...which solves your problem of "It is very hard when I render a single post"

Comment: @MarkMerritt It was just an occasion how hard to read the data everytime for this design. I am looking for something https://medium.com/@adamlangsner/4-ways-to-model-polymorphic-relationships-in-rails-5-4c98101ed900.

Comment: Can't understand why you guys kept on hold @meagar

Comment: It's on hold because it can't be answered in its current state. Again...this answer actually solves the issue you outlined. Any other answers relating to your data model will be completely subjective.